# Python RGB image transfer to YUV444

Tags: python, pytorch, rgb, yuv

Is there any way to transfer RGB image to YUV444 format in Python?
I notice that the transfer in opencv or pil lib belongs to YCbCr, right?
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983265/rgb-to-yuv-conversion-and-accessing-y-u-and-v-channels

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply cvtColor twice as follows:

```
# image is in RGB format
img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
```

Update:

I had not noticed COLOR_RGB2YUV is present in cv2. Thanks @Rotem. Hence the solution can be achieved by applying that instead.

```
img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV)
```

Comment: But [there is](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html) `cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV`. Can you please explain why we have to apply `cvtColor` twice?